# Sound Setting interface changed after reinstall alsa-base and pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Previously the sound setting interface was like this:
[image]

Today I reinstalled `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

The audio setting panel became like this:

[image]

Also I found the navigation icons `All Settings` and `Sound` now becomes a single `<` button.

I'm wondering if there's any way to restore the previous sound setting interface.

Comment: Looks like GNOME 3 transition. Can you try running `unity-control-center` and `gnome-control-center` and write here the results? Maybe just installing `unity-control-center` will help?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Zj3H4ady

Comment: https://pastebin.com/e528Fxuh

Comment: After removing `gnome-control-center` by `apt-get remove gnome-control-center`, the previous setting user interface comes back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `gnome-control-center` that got installed instead of `unity-control-center`.

```
sudo apt install unity-control-center
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue and was soooo happy to find an answer. I wonder why on earth unity-panel disappeared if I purged a completely different package(s)?

Comment: `unity-control-center` is being deprecated, maybe it was just an upgrade, not a deletion. This solution is just a temporary workaround until `unity-control-center` is completely removed from repositories AFAIU.

Comment: Well, the question is about 16.04 and it's LTS, so I guess it's here to stay for a while.